# EntityFieldQuery select entity if at least one tid is in the array?

Tags: entities, database

This seems like it would be a common need but I don't see how it can be done with the operators available. I have a taxonomy reference field that allows multiple values. I would like to construct an EntityFieldQuery that selects the entity if at least one of the tid's is in the given array.

```
$query->fieldCondition('field_tags', 'tid', $tid_array, 'CONTAINS_ONE');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is:

`$query->fieldCondition('field_tags', 'tid', $tid_array);`

From [`EntityFieldQuery::addFieldCondition()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AaddFieldCondition/7):
"The operator can be omitted, and will default to 'IN' if the value is an array, or to '=' otherwise."

Comment: I know that the operator defaults to 'IN', but does this return every entity where even one of the multiple-valued field values is in the array? It seems to be returning zero rows for me, but I may have a separate problem.

Comment: Works for me. Yes it returns every entity where even one of the multiple-valued field values is in the array. I'm using Drupal 7.15. Cheers.